# cordova plugins delayed execution on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am building an Ionic hybrid app and I have 4 plugins installed.

1. cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
2. cordova-plugin-app-version
3. cordova-plugin-geolocation
4. cordova-plugin-contacts

All of them work as expected on Android however, on iOS, whenever I trigger the plugin (usually with a button click), nothing happens, if I double click the app (or if I minimize and open up the app again), the plugins has executed and is displaying what I see on Android.

I have tried wrapping the call to the plugin in a $timeout but that didn't do anything different.

Any help would be appreciated as I have search all over hell on this and can't seem to find the issue.

Here is my apple setup:

- Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.2
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
- ios-deploy version: Not installed
- ios-sim version: Not installed
- OS: MacOS Sierra
- Node Version: v6.10.1
- Xcode version: Xcode 8.3.2 Build version 8E002

Comment: what if you dont double click the app? is it still executing after some time? I dont thing its anything to do with plugin

Comment: It never does, but as soon as I double click the home button, it displays immediately.  I don't disagree that it's not about the plugin, it's most likely about my setup, but I can't be the first/only person to ever encounter this.

Comment: The culprit was the content security policy in my index.html file.
Replacing it with this:
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap://ready file://* *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">

Fixed the problem